# How to remove the adaptive average pool layer from vgg19?

Tags: deep-learning, vision, vgg-net

I have loaded the pre-trained model of vgg19. How to remove the adaptive average pool layer which is present before the classifier?

Comment: Which framework are you using? tensorflow, keras, pytorch?

Comment: @mrzo In pytorch i would like to know how i should be doing this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PyTorch and torchVision model, you can disable the use of the last maxpool layer like this -

```
nn.Sequential(*list(vgg.features._modules.values())[:-1])
```

Here all the layers are in an array, and not including the last element does the trick.

Comment: thanks. but, doing this also removes the max pooling layer. how to retain the max pooling and remove only the adaptive avg pooling layer?

Comment: and how to drop only the Dense layers at the end retaining both max and adaptive-avg pool layers?

Comment: my torch version is `1.12.1+cu113` and torchvision's is `0.13.1+cu113` on python 3.7.13 on Ubuntu 18.04.